# Unexpected syntax error unexpected string when referencing JS from HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Alright, I downloaded this off Github trying to run it locally/modify it. https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/InteractiveRepulsionEffect/interactive-repulsive-effect.zip

The main index.html calls the JS in with: `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.0ffbaba978f8a0c5e2d0.js"></script>` which seems to be a minified version of app.js which I want to modify.

File structure looks like:

[image]

I changed the html to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/scripts/app.js"></script>` which is the correct filepath to the JS that makes the scene, but I then get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

on line 1 of app.js which is:

```
import 'styles/index.scss';
import Cone from './elements/cone';
import Box from './elements/box';
import Tourus from './elements/tourus';
```

I tried changing this path, it doesn't matter. It just doesn't "like" the line. What is going on here? How can I reference the editable JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, you have to place yourself in the first-demo folder and modify your app js. Then run

```
npm install
```

to install webpack and any missing packages (just once). Then you can run

```
npm run build
```

and it will rebuild your public folder with your changes. Better yet, you can just

```
npm run start
```

and you will see a hot reload of your changes when you modify app.js in

```
http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. But what about when I need to host it - I was using firebase previously

Comment: Also what is npm build doing? It gives me a warning that it has no arguments

Comment: @PatrikRikama-Hinnenberg npm build doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: npm run-script build does something :)

Comment: As @ceejayoz stated, you can see the command inside your package.json, you have:

  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  }

Make sure to write 'run' after 'npm': npm RUN build, what it does is build your deployable public folder with your html, css and js. There are many ways to host it, but usually (I use AWS S3 with Cloudfront) you just need to upload your public folder and get the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The JavaScript code you've got isn't ready to be run in a browser.

Those `public/app.xxxxxxxxxx.js` files are what's ready to run in a browser, and they're likely compiled by Webpack (or something similar). Your repository has some sort of "build" process in place - chances are you can look at the `scripts` section of `package.json` to see the available build commands.

Comment: For example, in https://github.com/iondrimba/interactive-repulsive-effect/blob/master/first-demo/package.json, `npm run start` will run your app in development mode. `npm run build` will build it for production. You will need to do `npm install` prior.

Comment: yes @ceejayoz is right and then my machine takes of when it runs this program:)

Comment: Got it, thanks. How can I then host the project say using firebase?

Comment: @skyguy You'd be deploying the assets in the `public` folder. Firebase has a `predeploy` step that could generate your production assets automatically, I believe.

Comment: The public folder provided by the repo is their code though, and I want to deploy my tweaked version as I go. Is that what you're saying predeploy would do?

Comment: Yes, your `pre-deploy` script would run the `build` command. That builds new versions of the assets in `public`.